# What is the reason to not allow smartphones and laptops in checked baggage?

Tags: air-travel, airport-security, thailand, hand-luggage

In Krabi, Thailand I was checking in baggage and there was a sign saying that e.g. smartphones, laptops (but also handbags) are not allowed in checked baggage. I had to put my (broken) smartphone into my backpack that was my hand luggage.

What is the rationale behind it? Do they think that bombs are less dangerous in the cabin after all? This contradicts what I have learned so far.

The airline is Thai Lion and this is a domestic flight to Bangkok.

Comment: What if they think that elephants are more dangerous than crocodiles?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is easier to handle a burning phone or laptop, if it is in the cabin, instead of the cargo hold.

Lithium batteries can catch fire pretty quickly, which already caused at least one plane crash.

Regarding small handbags, the issue here could be the size.  Esp. on airports where you have automated baggage systems, small items could fall between gaps etc. and block the whole system.

Comment: Makes sense, do you also know the rationale behind hand bags?

Comment: If you mean small handbags, then i guess it's the size. Esp. on airports where you have automated baggage systems, small items could fall between gaps etc. and block the whole system.

Comment: No, actually **in** my suitcase.

Comment: For those who are curious about the plane crash mentioned above:  I assume this is a reference to [UPS Airlines Flight 6.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UPS_Airlines_Flight_6)

Comment: Re burning phone: what are the statistical chances of that happening?  Funny how USA and UK have introduced the [exact opposite logic](http://www.wired.co.uk/article/uk-laptop-ban-flights-explained).  `Terrorism` excuse can quickly be applied to all countries, making ownership of such electronic devices much less convenient and more susceptible to opportunity theft. You cant have it both ways.